# Setting Input to take multiple layers in QGIS Python processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am writing a Python script that I will add in to my processing toolbox. I have got the script working so now just a case of setting my Inputs and Outputs. I am struggling with one, I am trying to set it so the user can enter multiple layers as one of the inputs just like how it is set up on the Merge Vector Layer tool below.

[image]

I have been trying the following two bits of code to try and set this up but it's a bit of a guess really.

How do I correctly format these?

```
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers(
                name,
                description,
                QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry
            )
        )

Map = self.parameterAsLayerList(
            parameters,
            name,
            context
        )
```

Comment: What's the question here :)? I think you've nailed it with the code snippets you posted. That's the way of adding such a parameter to a processing script as well as to read it.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example of usage is below. Don't forget to import the `QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers` class.

```py
...
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers(
            'LAYERS',
            self.tr("Input layers"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry))

 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        layers = self.parameterAsLayerList(parameters, 'LAYERS', context)
        for layer in layers:
            #do something with layer
...
```